# SQL-query help remove image-size at the end of a filename

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a lot of image URL's in my databases that looks like this (with different heights): http://url.com/uploads/filename-980xheight.jpg

I would like to change all those to http://url.com/uploads/filename.jpg

I'm really struggling to find a solution that feels sound.

It's in a Wordpress-blog so all these URL's are located in the table wp_posts and column post_content.

Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: is it always `filename-numberxnumber.jpg`? We get better information when you provide a data example.

Comment: Yes, and -980 is persistent, only the second number is changing.

Comment: Hint use string function replace

Comment: Most easy solution would be to use CONCAT and nested SUBSTRING_INDEX functions to split the string on (`-`)  something like this https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/Ysn8xydwuHLHqVmXEey4R/0

Comment: You mean they are inside a column that contains lots of other text besides the urls?

Comment: Wordpress instances automatically resize images when uploaded via the Media Library and give the resized copies names like the ones you mention. This is controlled via Settings > Media on your dashboard. If you change the filenames, your Wordpress posts containing images may render incorrectly.

Comment: Yes, they are inside a column with a lot of other text, and the url.com/uploads are different everytime like url.com/uploads/01/01 or url.com/uploads/01/02 etc.

It's an export from a different Wordpress, the new one doesn't use the resize images, only original sizes, that's why I want to remove them.